# хочу, проверить слово, если он есть в массиве obj, пусть напечатает, вместе с возрастом, из класса David. если нет пусть напишет, имени нет

Tags: java

```
public class Run {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  

ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();  

 obj.add("Ajeet");  
 obj.add("Harry");   
 obj.add("Chaitanya");  
 obj.add("Steve");  
 obj.add("Anuj");  

    Scanner sсanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.print("Ввод имени  : ");   
    String s = sсanner.nextLine();  

    David d = new David();  

    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Ajeet" ) || s.equalsIgnoreCase("Harry")||   
    s.equalsIgnoreCase("Chaitanya") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("Steve") ||   
    s.equalsIgnoreCase("Anuj")){  

    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Ajeet")) {  
    System.out.println("Vozrast " + s + " : " + d.ajeet );  

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Harry")){  
            System.out.println("Vozrast " + s + " : " + d.harry );  
        }  
         }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Класс David

```
   public class David {

    int ajeet = 21;
    int harry = 34;
    int chaitanya = 23;
    int steve = 22;
    int anuj = 24;
 }
```

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759446/177345